# Why is there a performance difference between the order of a nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.x

I have a process that loops through two lists, one being relatively large while the other being significantly smaller.

Example:

```
larger_list = list(range(15000))
smaller_list = list(range(2500))

for ll in larger_list:
    for sl in smaller_list:            
        pass
```

I scaled the sized down of the lists to test performance, and I noticed there is a decent difference between which list is looped through first.

```
import timeit

larger_list = list(range(150))
smaller_list = list(range(25))


def large_then_small():
    for ll in larger_list:
        for sl in smaller_list:
            pass


def small_then_large():
    for sl in smaller_list:
        for ll in larger_list:
            pass


print('Larger -> Smaller: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(large_then_small)))
print('Smaller -> Larger: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(small_then_large)))

>>> Larger -> Smaller: 114.884992572
>>> Smaller -> Larger: 98.7751009799
```

At first glance, they look identical - however there is 16 second difference between the two functions.

Why is that?

Comment: Note that that 16 second difference is out of about 100, and if there was actual work in the inner loop, it'd be 16 seconds out of like an hour.

Comment: Interesting. If we count the number of for-statements executed in the function large_then_small it is 1 + 150 = 151 and in the small_then_large it is  1 + 25 = 26 (please note that the number of inner loops excecuted is the same - I am only talking about the number of for-statements that get executed). 

So is this maybe connected to the overhead in setting up for-loops?

Comment: Each time you execute a `for` loop python will create a new iterator over the sequence. So the larger and then smaller will simply call the method for obtaining an iterator over the smaller list many more times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you disassemble one of your functions you get:

```
>>> dis.dis(small_then_large)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 34)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (smaller_list)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                23 (to 33)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (sl)

  3          13 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 30)
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (larger_list)
             19 GET_ITER
        >>   20 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 29)
             23 STORE_FAST               1 (ll)

  4          26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
        >>   29 POP_BLOCK
        >>   30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   33 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Looking at address 29 & 30, it looks like these will execute every time the inner loop ends.  The two loops look basically the same, but these two instructions are executed each time the inner loop exits.  Having the smaller number on the inside would cause these to be executed more often, hence increasing the time (vs the larger number on the inner loop).

Comment: BTW, this isn't a python thing. The same is true in other languages as well.

Answer (score 2):

This same phenomenon was under discussion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585308/why-is-iterating-over-a-short-list-of-long-lists-faster-than-iterating-over-a-lo) duplicate and got me interested in what goes on in the C land of CPython. Built python with:

```
% ./configure --enable-profiling
% make coverage
```

## Tests

```
% ./python -c "larger_list = list(range(15000))
smaller_list = list(range(2500))
for sl in smaller_list:
    for ll in larger_list: 
        pass"
% mv gmon.out soflgmon.out

% ./python -c "larger_list = list(range(15000))
smaller_list = list(range(2500))
for ll in larger_list:
    for sl in smaller_list:
        pass"
% mv gmon.out lofsgmon.out
```

## Results

Short list of long lists (total time for a single run 1.60):

```
% gprof python soflgmon.out|head -n40
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 46.25      0.74     0.74     3346     0.00     0.00  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
 25.62      1.15     0.41 37518735     0.00     0.00  insertdict
 14.38      1.38     0.23 37555121     0.00     0.00  lookdict_unicode_nodummy
  7.81      1.50     0.12 37506675     0.00     0.00  listiter_next
  4.06      1.57     0.07 37516233     0.00     0.00  PyDict_SetItem
  0.62      1.58     0.01     2095     0.00     0.00  _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
  0.62      1.59     0.01        3     0.00     0.00  untrack_dicts
  0.31      1.59     0.01                             _PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash
  0.31      1.60     0.01                             listiter_len
  0.00      1.60     0.00    87268     0.00     0.00  visit_decref
  0.00      1.60     0.00    73592     0.00     0.00  visit_reachable
  0.00      1.60     0.00    71261     0.00     0.00  _PyThreadState_UncheckedGet
  0.00      1.60     0.00    49742     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Alloc
  0.00      1.60     0.00    48922     0.00     0.00  PyObject_Malloc
  0.00      1.60     0.00    48922     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Malloc
  0.00      1.60     0.00    47487     0.00     0.00  PyDict_GetItem
  0.00      1.60     0.00    44246     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Free
  0.00      1.60     0.00    43637     0.00     0.00  PyObject_Free
  0.00      1.60     0.00    30034     0.00     0.00  slotptr
  0.00      1.60     0.00    24892     0.00     0.00  type_is_gc
  0.00      1.60     0.00    24170     0.00     0.00  r_byte
  0.00      1.60     0.00    23774     0.00     0.00  PyErr_Occurred
  0.00      1.60     0.00    20371     0.00     0.00  _PyType_Lookup
  0.00      1.60     0.00    19930     0.00     0.00  PyLong_FromLong
  0.00      1.60     0.00    19758     0.00     0.00  r_string
  0.00      1.60     0.00    19080     0.00     0.00  _PyLong_New
  0.00      1.60     0.00    18887     0.00     0.00  lookdict_unicode
  0.00      1.60     0.00    18878     0.00     0.00  long_dealloc
  0.00      1.60     0.00    17639     0.00     0.00  PyUnicode_InternInPlace
  0.00      1.60     0.00    17502     0.00     0.00  rangeiter_next
  0.00      1.60     0.00    14776     0.00     0.00  PyObject_GC_UnTrack
  0.00      1.60     0.00    14578     0.00     0.00  descr_traverse
  0.00      1.60     0.00    13520     0.00     0.00  r_long
  0.00      1.60     0.00    13058     0.00     0.00  PyUnicode_New
  0.00      1.60     0.00    12298     0.00     0.00  _Py_CheckFunctionResult
  ...
```

Long list of short lists (total time for a single run 1.64):

```
gprof python lofsgmon.out|head -n40
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 48.78      0.80     0.80     3346     0.00     0.00  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
 17.99      1.09     0.29 37531168     0.00     0.00  insertdict
 11.59      1.28     0.19 37531675     0.00     0.00  listiter_next
 11.28      1.47     0.18 37580156     0.00     0.00  lookdict_unicode_nodummy
  6.71      1.58     0.11 37528666     0.00     0.00  PyDict_SetItem
  1.22      1.60     0.02                             _PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash
  0.61      1.61     0.01     5525     0.00     0.00  update_one_slot
  0.61      1.62     0.01      120     0.00     0.00  PyDict_Merge
  0.30      1.62     0.01    18178     0.00     0.00  lookdict_unicode
  0.30      1.63     0.01    11988     0.00     0.00  insertdict_clean
  0.30      1.64     0.01                             listiter_len
  0.30      1.64     0.01                             listiter_traverse
  0.00      1.64     0.00    96089     0.00     0.00  _PyThreadState_UncheckedGet
  0.00      1.64     0.00    87245     0.00     0.00  visit_decref
  0.00      1.64     0.00    74743     0.00     0.00  visit_reachable
  0.00      1.64     0.00    62232     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Alloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    61412     0.00     0.00  PyObject_Malloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    61412     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Malloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    59815     0.00     0.00  PyDict_GetItem
  0.00      1.64     0.00    55231     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_Free
  0.00      1.64     0.00    54622     0.00     0.00  PyObject_Free
  0.00      1.64     0.00    36274     0.00     0.00  PyErr_Occurred
  0.00      1.64     0.00    30034     0.00     0.00  slotptr
  0.00      1.64     0.00    24929     0.00     0.00  type_is_gc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    24617     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_GC_Alloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    24617     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_GC_Malloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    24170     0.00     0.00  r_byte
  0.00      1.64     0.00    20958     0.00     0.00  PyObject_GC_Del
  0.00      1.64     0.00    20371     0.00     0.00  _PyType_Lookup
  0.00      1.64     0.00    19918     0.00     0.00  PyLong_FromLong
  0.00      1.64     0.00    19758     0.00     0.00  r_string
  0.00      1.64     0.00    19068     0.00     0.00  _PyLong_New
  0.00      1.64     0.00    18845     0.00     0.00  long_dealloc
  0.00      1.64     0.00    18507     0.00     0.00  _PyObject_GC_New
  0.00      1.64     0.00    17639     0.00     0.00  PyUnicode_InternInPlace
  ...
```

The difference is marginal (2.4%), and profiling adds to run time, so it is difficult to say how much it actually would've been. The total time also includes the creation of the test lists, so that hides the true difference further.

The reason for the 16s difference in the original test is that `timeit.timeit` runs the given statement or function `number=1000000` times by default, so that would add up to a whopping 40,000s in this case. Don't quote that value though, as it is an artifact of profiling. With your original test code and non profiling python3 on this machine I get:

```
Larger -> Smaller: 40.29234626500056
Smaller -> Larger: 33.09413992699956
```

which would mean a difference of

```
In [1]: (40.29234626500056-33.09413992699956)/1000000
Out[1]: 7.198206338001e-06
```

per single run (7.2µs), 18% in total.

So as stated in the [former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710710/2681632), [`POP_BLOCK`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L2100) gets executed more, but it's not just that, but the whole inner loop setup:

```
  0.00      1.64     0.00    16521     0.00     0.00  PyFrame_BlockSetup
  0.00      1.64     0.00    16154     0.00     0.00  PyFrame_BlockPop
```

Compared to the short list of long lists:

```
  0.00      1.60     0.00     4021     0.00     0.00  PyFrame_BlockSetup
  0.00      1.60     0.00     3748     0.00     0.00  set_next
  0.00      1.60     0.00     3654     0.00     0.00  PyFrame_BlockPop
```

That has negligible impact though.