# Why is iterating over a short list of long lists faster than iterating over a long list of short lists?

Tags: python, performance-testing

How come in Python that double for-looping over a short list of long lists is faster than the same operation on a long list of short lists?

Consider the following example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def long_short(n):
    """Iterate through n long list of 10 long lists"""
    x = [["inner"]*10]*n

    start = dt.now()
    counter = 0
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            counter += 1

    return (dt.now() - start).microseconds/1000

def short_long(n):
    """Iterate through 10 long list of n long lists"""
    x = [["inner"]*n]*10

    start = dt.now()
    counter = 0
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            counter += 1

    return (dt.now() - start).microseconds/1000

x, y1, y2 = [], [], []
for i, n in enumerate(range(1000, 1000000, 10000)):
    x.append(n)
    y1.append(long_short(n))
    y2.append(short_long(n))
    print n,

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.plot(x, y1, c="b", label="Long list of short lists")
ax2 = plt.plot(x, y2, c="g", label="Short list of long lists")
plt.xlabel("n", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)", fontsize=16)
plt.legend(loc=2, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

This will produce the figure:

[image]

I know this is an extreme example, because it is rare that one needs to loop over such big nested lists, but then again, I can imagine matrix operations that require accessing every element by double for-looping over `range(N)` and `range(M)`, for which case this result suggests that one should keep the shortest loop as the outer loop.

**Edit:**

I initially switched the result around in the title and the written text above. I updated the title and text to correct for this. The code and the figure is unchanged by this error!

### Post duplicate update:

As pointed out in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710710/3986879) in the original question, the reason for the performance difference is simply that when double-looping over a short list of long lists, **an inner for-loop is created far more times** than in the reverse case.

Comment: Does the pattern remain if you made the inner lists independent objects, rather than all references to the same list? Try `x = [["inner"]*10 for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Am I completely reading your graph wrong, or isn't it the other way around? (sl of ll is faster than ll of sl).

Comment: @Ilja, if you are reading it wrong then so am I

Comment: Huh. My tests said long-list-of-short-ones was faster, but this graph does seem to have the short list of long ones in the lead.

Comment: @UlfAslak, can you clarify whether the graph or the question text is correct? Perhaps rerun the test to make sure the effect is reproducible and the graph corresponds to the right version of the code.

Comment: Just did a `[[0]*10]*1000000` vs. `[[0]*1000000]*10` on this machine, the latter won by ~33% (195ms vs. 130ms).

Comment: @Ilja: See if the effect reverses if you make the long list even bigger.

Comment: I updated the question including the title, since I accidentally swapped the result around. Thanks for noticing @Ilja! So the figure and code was correct all along and still is: a short list of long lists is faster.

Comment: So my guess is that having to do 1+1000000 vs. 1+10 [`SETUP_LOOP`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3018)s plays a role, but this is just a hunch. Did not actually measure that, but that's about the difference when thinking in bytecode.

Comment: Strange... I can't replicate my earlier results. The short list of long ones wins even for the list sizes where I already measured the opposite effect. There must have been something else going on the first time.

Comment: @user2357112 tried adding an order of magnitude, but the difference stayed pretty constant – short of longs won by ~33%.

Comment: @Ilja that makes perfect sense. tried with generators also, and the difference is still there.

Comment: Well, I've consistently failed to reproduce the results of my first test, and it doesn't look like anyone else is seeing cache-related performance effects. I wish I could figure out what was happening differently with my earlier tests, but I guess the best I can do for now is delete my answer.