# Nested cycles are faster than flat in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization, profiling

In a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585308/why-is-iterating-over-a-short-list-of-long-lists-faster-than-iterating-over-a-lo) question one wondered why nesting two cycles one way (longer in shorter) is faster the other (shorter in longer).

Now I've run into a flat cycle running slower than nested. How could it be?

```
from time import perf_counter as clock
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def long_short():
    start = clock()
    counter = 0
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(10):
            counter += 1
    return (clock() - start)*1e6

def short_long():
    start = clock()
    counter = 0
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(100):
            counter += 1
    return (clock() - start)*1e6

def single():
    start = clock()
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        counter += 1
    return (clock() - start)*1e6

y1, y2, y3 = [], [], []
for i in range(30):
    y1.append(long_short())
    y2.append(short_long())
    y3.append(single())

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.plot(y1, c="b", label="Longer loop over shorter")
ax2 = plt.plot(y2, c="g", label="Shorter loop over longer")
ax3 = plt.plot(y3, c="r", label="Single loop")
plt.xlabel("n", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Time (us)", fontsize=16)
plt.legend(loc=2, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note, you aren't looping over lists.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I know, range is not a list. I thought I removed all mentionings of lists. It's not critical though.

Comment: I don't think you can draw conclusions based on executing each function once. Suggest you use `timeit` instead to run them multiple times and compare the mean runtimes.

Comment: Mmmmm well, it would make a difference if `range` produced a list in this case, I think.

Comment: Those are microseconds, just to be clear. "ms" usually means millisecond. I'm just pointing it out because I was shocked when I first thought that was milliseconds

Comment: @martineau actually it runs 30 times, not one time. I ran timeit as well. This plot gives more readily reproducible results than timeit (more evident as well).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. Yes, it is us of course.

Comment: Now, just *musing*. But your short ranges only include pre-cached integers. For integers greater than 255, Python has to create *entirely new integer objects*, which could very well explain this difference. But again, just speculation, can't figure out a good way to test this

Comment: I think your graphs show that something unusual happens on about the 15th call for some of the functions, correct? If so, then they don't mean exactly what you claim.

Comment: In the case of the nested loop scenarios it might be worth measuring the average iteration time of the outer loop separately from the average iteration time of the inner loop. The plot of average iteration iteration time of the inner loop must more or less coincide with the plot of average iteration time of the flat loop. If it doesn't coincide, that might give a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: @martineau I'm using walltime for benchmarking. OS is doing something in the meanwhile. It's pretty usual that some outbreaks happen, otherwise running it once would be enough.

Comment: Antony: I know that — which is why I usually just compare average runtimes instead of looking at series of individual ones, so wouldn't have even bothered plotting a bunch of them like you're doing, which is more of a distraction than anything else IMO.

Comment: Aha! Try looping over `rng = itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(100)]*10)` in single, put that construction before `start`, but note, now we only ever use pre-cached integers, and I'm seeing the red and gree being essentially indistinguishable.

Comment: @martineau the best way to visualize benchmarks is histogram. For instance both mean and min (there're proponents for both approaches) are unable to "feel" multimodal distribution (eg two peaks). In the context of this quiestion the time difference is too delicate for timeit to give evident enough results. It drown deep in std deviation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it definitely something to do with small integers optimization, as the effect vanishes for a larger number of loop iterations. As for `from_iterable` - yes, they become indistinquishable, but I don't see where you pre-cache integers here. `range` object doesn't get converted into a list here, it's still a generator.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, small integers optimization *is* the answer! I've changed second loop to `for j in range(300, 400):` in short_long and the green line went above the red one. Will you post an answer? I'd accept it.

Comment: I'm currently at work, will do it later if no one else does. We are only ever using pre-cached integers in the `itertools.chain` version, because we loop over 0-100 ten times.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok. Yes, legitimate.

Comment: This may well never be of practical importance, but I thought it was interesting: looping over `itertools.repeat(1, 1000)` is 10-15% faster than the short-over-long and chain approaches (and about 25% faster than just looping over `range(1000)`).